# Reporte de test unittest s

Tags: html, python, selenium, gmail, pruebas-unitarias

Necesito hacer un envio de reportes o almacenar el estado de los test en algun documento para poder enviarlos por email, probe con HTMLTestRunner y al enviar el archivo por email se ve mal y no funciona ya que tiene javascript

```
test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([create_pulverizadora,])

outfile = open(dire + '/PruebaPulverizadoraPrueba.html', 'w')

runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title='Reporte Test Pulverizadora' )

runner.run(test_suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Allure2](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) suele ser mi opcion siempre. Puedes exportar el reporte de multiples maneras y en diferentes idiomas. Despues solo tendrias que enviarlo.

[image]